# How to set JavaScript breakpoints in Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to debug JavaScript code using Visual Studio 2010, but I can't set breakpoints.

How can I do this?

I just noticed something, every time I try to call a function, no matter what function, in JavaScript, somehow [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and Microsoft's Ajax framework JavaScript captures it and checks if the document is ready (`document.onready` or other) and never returns the control back to the function I'm calling! Why on earth is it doing this? I've never asked for it to!

All I have are references to these libraries, script/link references as you do on the top of your master page.

This is ridiculous, how do I fix it?

Comment: http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/debugging_javascript_in_visual_studio.htm

Comment: try using the notifyScriptLoaded call at the bottom of your script files http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310952.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your script is in a separate script file (.js), then you can just use F9 to set a breakpoint on a line.

You can't set a breakpoint if the script is incorporated in another file like an aspx file. For cases like that, use the `debugger;` javascript statement to force a break at a certain spot.

Also make sure that you are working with the latest version of your javascript file, do a Ctrl-F5 in IE if necessary to force a fresh reload of the file.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `debugger;` statement before the line where you want to stop execution and debug.

#### Example

```
var test = "testString";
debugger; // stops execution and can start debugging
test += "newly added";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're attaching to a process, you can specify that you want to attach to script in the dialog that comes up. But then it'll be only script and not managed code.

Just use [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) in Firefox.