# How to use breakpoints in Javascript code in .ASPX page of Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I have Javascript in my .aspx design source page. How can i set breakpoints and run as i set it for a .cs page. I am using Visual Studio 2008 for my coding.
I have browsed for the use of debugger. But i couldn't get how to use it properly. If debugger; is used, can someone elaborate on how its used.

Comment: Have you tried to set breakpoints in Java script?

Comment: Ya, but it doesn't hit it

Comment: Should I add any process to activate the breakpoint for Java Script ?

Comment: Why don't you use the Debugger of your browser?

Comment: Use Firebug for firefox to debug javascript.

Comment: use this link for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251599/how-to-set-javascript-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2008-or-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I tried using Debugger of my IE. But it crashes everytime

Comment: Try to erase your cache of your browser.Sometimes you change your javascript but browser get the script from cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a debugger; statement and you're using IE, the browser will throw a "Script Debugging" error and prompt you for a debugging tool, you can select VS 2008 from the list.

Make sure to have the "Disable Script Debugging" options in IE unchecked.

Alternatively, you can use "Debug > Attach To Process" and attach the debugger to your browser processes, after that you can put a regular break point from visual studio on your javascript code and it will work.

Comment: It shows "Breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Comment: Its ok, sometimes it does that, but when you refresh your page the break point gets hit.